# Installing Snimpy and libsmi

Tags: python, linux, windows, snmp, snimpy

I have spent hours trying and failing to install [snimpy](http://snimpy.readthedocs.org/en/0.8.0/).

#### Windows

I have tried installing it on both my Windows PC and the server to which I'll be sending SNMP requests, but I've failed on both counts; on Windows, I have managed to successfully run

```
easy_install snimpy
```

to get it installed, but when I try to run it, it complains that it can't find `smi.h`, which according to the Snimpy documentation means I need to install libsmi on my PC. However I can't find any guide on how to install libsmi on Windows - could anybody direct me to anything on that?

#### Linux

I've also tried installing it on the server, which runs Red Hat Linux. But I can't even get passed the `easy_install snimpy` stage; when I try to run it I get lots of strange errors. After some hunting around apparently the fix is getting the Python Development Headers. On Debian/Ubuntu this is done by using

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

but that doesn't work on this Red Hat system; I've tried using

```
yum install python-dev
```

but I get the following message:

> ```
> Setting up Install Process
> No package python-dev available.
> Error: Nothing to do
> ```

#### Question

I have no idea how to get this to work or how to otherwise install these headers.

Can anybody help me get this set up on either system?

Answer (score 1):

The package is `python-devel` on redhat:

`yum  install python-devel.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you need the development header for `SMI` lib.

On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libsmi2-dev
```